# Alignment issue for the review stats page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review-stats

E.g. [the triage review stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/stats) page for SO has different start Y-position for left and right columns:

> [image: review stats]

Also, text color for the left column is **gray**, for the right column is **black**.

Problem still exists even after winterbash ends (see comments).

Comment: That's nothing compared to some [mod tool issues](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3062/52050)

Comment: Probably because of the hats... better wait until Winterbash is over and see if it persists. (by the way how come there are no hats in your screenshot?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I specifically selected the "I hate hats" option. I think in this case everything should be same as was before winter-bash season.

Comment: Probably it's not technically feasible, they don't have two separate views for each page. But if you selected that, how come I see you're wearing hat?

Comment: @ShadowWizard whereas first line for both columns contains always same profile it's weird that hat on the left avatar makes some position shift, but for the right - doesn't.

Comment: There might be a bug there, but since it's not fatal, and will go away soon, not sure it's worth the team's efforts.

Comment: @ShadowWizard when I look at the revision on the page's bottom I realize that team is on holidays now :)

Comment: Issue can be easily solved with removing class `.user-info` from first `.task-stat-leaderboard` container.

Comment: @vp_arth if such action can solve this issue, I think your comment should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Issue can be easily solved with removing `.user-info` class from first `.task-stat-leaderboard` container.

#### Why it helps

Let's take a look onto `DOM`:

```
<div class="stats-mainbar">
  <table class="task-stat-table"></table>
  <div class="task-stat-leaderboard user-info" style="float: left;"></div>
  <div class="task-stat-leaderboard" style="float: right;"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, first `.task-stat-leaderboard` block has excess `.user-info` class:

```
.user-info {
    box-sizing: border-box;   /* No effect for container*/
    padding: 5px 6px 7px 7px; /*! Unnecessary shifts here */
    width: 200px;             /*overriden by .task-stat-leaderboard*/
    color: #6a737c;           /*! Text color */
}
```

This css class was designed for small user cards in the table inside this container.

#### Fixed view

[image: Layout without .user-info]