# Roadmap or trello dashboard with current dev team tasks/plans

Tags: discussion, feature-request, development

We have this post about changes that were applied: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/260198).

But I didn't find any convenient ways to check which tasks SE devs are working on right now.

Only [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) has some abstract tasks/plans without any dates.

I've found a lot of important questions from other members, which were ignored, like mine about localization ([How localized sites could translate strings before update actually rolled out?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314599/260198)).

No comments, no deadlines, nothing. It discourages the desire to write anything at all.

Even small fixes "[Alignment issue for the review stats page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288893/260198)", or an important question about mod tools "[Moderator tools design issues and inconsistencies](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3062)"...

Could you create a public roadmap page or trello dashboard, or Gantt chart with current dev team tasks/plans?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange

Answer (score 4):

*[2018 monthly product team updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305560/2018-monthly-product-team-updates)* is the best place to check for what we are focused on for any given month. (And, I need to write this month's update.)

Comment: Thanks, but what's about the part of being heard? I mean, a lot of posts looks like they were literally ignored by the SE team.

Comment: @Suvitruf SE can't get back to every single request. For some tips on how to make it more likely that SE will get back to a certain request, see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).